# How to get Serial Number (processor tray) with Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, serial-number

By typing : system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep 'Serial Number'
I get 2 serial numbers.

The first ("Serial Number (system)") can be put in `NSString` by :

```
(NSString *)IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault, "IOService:/"), CFSTR(kIOPlatformSerialNumberKey), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)
```

and I didn't find how I can get the second : Serial Number (processor tray)

Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In a more elegant way :)

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main()
{
    CFTypeRef aCFProperty;

    if ((aCFProperty = IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault, "IOService:/"), CFSTR("processor-memory-board-serial-number"), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0)) != NULL )
    {
        NSLog(@"Processor tray Serial Number : %@", aCFProperty);
        CFRelease(aCFProperty);
    }

    return 1;
}
```

Then : clang SnTray.m -framework IOKit -framework Foundation -o SnTray.o

Then ./SnTray.o

i cant do more :)

Answer (score -1):

Answer:

```
(NSString *)IORegistryEntryCreateCFProperty(IORegistryEntryFromPath(kIOMasterPortDefault, "IOService:/"), CFSTR("processor-memory-board-serial-number"), kCFAllocatorDefault, 0);
```